# Should I speak up to my managers boss?

Tags: resignation

I work in medical admin I was recently a small part of a project that made me crazy for so many reasons. In light of recent events I'm now reconsider staying at my current company.

My tiny part was transferring data.  In the big picture I was pretty small. There were 2 project leads and one project manager and many, others that weren't as hands on

I worked with one of the project leads for about 5 or 6 years but in different departments.. She started off as a CSR and somehow became a manager and then an administrator. (her education is cosmetology)

Our company is known for promoting staff who have very little formal education to management positions. 
To make a long story short, the project she led was a complete disaster.

As a manager, she is disorganized, easily overwhelmed,  has poor follow through and is quick to blame others....other people weren't doing what were supposed to or are "mean" to her

I saw her poor decision making skills, poor communication skills and inability to prioritize first hand. Honestly, it didnt matter to me because it was her name, not mine

I assumed when the project was over I would be done with her but to my surprise she is now the manager of my department and I now report to her.

My concern is this....she is now in charge of my department which for the most part works well. I have no confidence that if I do have to  bring issues to her she is capable of handling them. I don't trust her as a manager or a person.

Should I speak up or keep my mouth shut?

Comment: Why do you think you should speak up? Do you think they'll sack her on your say so?

Comment: Of course not, she seems untouchable.

Comment: @user93997, so why do you want to speak up?

Answer (score 9):

The repercussions of complaining about your manager usually outweigh the benefits if any. In your situation you are complaining that you don't trust her, when she hasn't actually done anything concrete yet as manager for your department. On top of that you're implying to her boss (the person you're complaining to) that he/she doesn't know what they're doing.

I can't see this ending positively for you, but might make you feel better if you're leaving anyway. In which case it's best to do after you have new employment sorted out.

In terms of actually making a change if you do, it seems unlikely that anything will eventuate beyond some talk of disgruntled employee etc,. . And if it does, it won't benefit you personally.

If you are going to resign, it's best to focus on where your career is headed and leave quietly on a positive note. Once you're gone you just shrug it off with 'Not my circus, not my monkeys'.

Comment: I have never seen a situation where this would end positively. Chain of command exists for a reason. Jumping the chain never ends well.

Answer (score -2):

From your question, you seem to have already set your mind to report your manager's disorganization, since you are affraid she will harm or disrupt the work you will bring to her.

If you have been working with her for about 5 or 6 years, gather written proof of that disorganization (examples where it harmed the project) and in the first instance she damages your work, you add that to your report and present it to her boss.

The risk you are incurring is that her boss may want her in that particular position due to the unlikelyhood of her getting a higher position (his/her (boss) position). So you could write the report in a way that excuses the disrupted work you deliver, but does not necessarily imply that she needs to be fired...